# How to create different session scenario in Sql Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to test result of a query having global temporary table in two different sessions in sql server. I am not able to understand that opening two different windows in SSMS pointing to same database will create two different sesstion or not. If I am mistaken in my question please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, two tabs in SSMS will definitely be two different sessions (i.e. @@SPID). You cannot have two separate windows open to the same session / SPID anyway.

There are a few ways to see what the SessionID / SPID is:

- The right side of the tab in SSMS has a number in parenthesis. This is the SPID. The tab title is formatted as:
  FileName - InstanceName.DatabaseName (LoginName (SPID))
- Status bar at the bottom, towards the right side, has a box formatted as:
  LoginName (SPID)
- In the query window, execute the following:
  `SELECT @@SPID;`